Rotating camera around object while keeping object in the center using THREE.js
I would like to camera in 3D around object in Three.js based on current mouse position. From user's perspective - I would like object to stay in the center of the screen and just see it rotating in 3D.
Important aspects:

the farther away from the center, the faster rotation is
when mouse points to a point away from the screen without moving: rotation is at constant speed in the same direction

I have two modules.
RotateObject3d - place where a texture is rendered, where mouseMoveEvent sits.
CoordinatesTransformer - has two function. First maps screen coordinates to cartesian coordinates, second calculates xEye, yEye, zEye and yDirection (yUp).
I personally dont know how to implement such rotation once we have xEye, yEye, zEye and yDirection.
Also I am not sure wheather I calculate above mentioned variables correctly.
Also, I do not think I wanna use Orbit for it because, later I will change coordinates obrtained via mouse movement to coordinates collected from eyeTracker library.
RotateObject3d:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js';
import CoordinateTransformer from './CoordinateTransformer';

const fieldOfView = 70;
const nearPlane = 0.1;
const farPlane = 300;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fieldOfView, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, nearPlane, farPlane);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const backgroundColor = "#808080";

const RotateObject3D = ( {selectedFileName }: { selectedFileName : string } ) => {
  const coordinateTransformer = new CoordinateTransformer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  let xEye = 0.00;
  let yEye = 0.00;
  let zEye = 0.00;
  let yUp = 1;
  let R = 12;

  camera.position.set(0, 0, R);

  useEffect(() => {
    scene.clear();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(backgroundColor);
    
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    const loader = new OBJLoader();
    let object3D: THREE.Object3D;
    const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();

    
    let mtlFileName = `./${selectedFileName }.mtl`; 
    let objFileName = `./${selectedFileName }.obj`;


    mtlLoader.load(
      mtlFileName,
      (materials) => {
        materials.preload();
        loader.setMaterials(materials);
        
        loader.load(
          objFileName,
        (object) => {
          object3D = object;
          scene.add(object);
          updateCameraToFitObject(camera, object);
        })
      }
    );

    const updateCameraToFitObject = (camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera, object: THREE.Object3D<THREE.Object3DEventMap>) => {
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
      const size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
      const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

      const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = size * 0.5;
      const halfFovY = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov * 0.5);
      const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);

      const direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(camera.position, center).normalize();
      camera.position.copy(direction.multiplyScalar(distance).add(center));

      camera.lookAt(center);
    };

    
    function handleMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
        const {x: xCoord, y: yCoord} = coordinateTransformer.screenToCartesianCoordinates(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        const {xEye: x, yEye: y, zEye: z, yUp: yDir} = coordinateTransformer.twoDimensionalToThreeDimensional(xCoord, yCoord);

        xEye = y;
        yEye = x;
        zEye = z;
        yUp = yDir;
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      if (object3D) {
          # what should I do here.

      }
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    
    animate();
  }, [selectedFileName]);

  return null;
}

export default RotateObject3D;

Coordinate transformer:
class CoordinateTransformer {
  private rotationSpeedFactor = 0.2;
  private theta = 0.0;
  private phi = 0.0;

  private yPixToAngle: number;
  private xPixToAngle: number;
  private screenWidth = 0;
  private screenHeight = 0;

  constructor(screenWidth: number, screenHeight: number) {
    this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
    this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
    this.yPixToAngle = 360 / screenHeight;
    this.xPixToAngle = 360 / screenWidth;
  }


  public screenToCartesianCoordinates = (screenX: number, screenY: number) => {
    const cartesianX = screenX - this.screenWidth / 2;
    const cartesianY = this.screenHeight / 2 - screenY;
    return { x: cartesianX, y: cartesianY };
  };

  public twoDimensionalToThreeDimensional = (x: number, y: number) => {
    this.theta = (x * this.xPixToAngle) % 360;
    this.phi = (y * this.yPixToAngle) % 360;
    
    const radianPhi = this.phi * Math.PI / 180;
    const radianTheta = this.theta * Math.PI / 180;
    
    const xEye = Math.cos(radianTheta) * Math.cos(radianPhi);
    const yEye = Math.sin(radianPhi);
    const zEye = Math.sin(radianTheta) * Math.cos(radianPhi);
    
    const yUp = (this.phi >= 90 && this.phi <= 270) ? -1 : 1;

    return {
      xEye: xEye,
      yEye: yEye,
      zEye: zEye,
      yUp: yUp,
    };
  };
}

export default CoordinateTransformer;


I need help with this one.

Have you looked at OrbitControls? You don't have to use it as-is, you can modify it to suit your use-case (like faster rotation based on target distance).
